# learn batch job parameters AX 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I need to learn parameters of batch job in batch job form.

Go to  the batch job form and find out the job description and first clicked on the view task, then click parameters. A dialog box like this will open;

[image]

Is it possible see in here parameters which selected when batch job seting up? If yes, how can do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The way you describe is the way to view the parameters with which the batch job has initially been set up.

Comment: actually I want to see the value of these parameters. For example, if the Name parameter is set to 'John Doe' when installing the batch, I want to see the 'John Doe' value on this screen

Comment: Look at `\Classes\Tutorial_RunbaseBatch`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preload de data

You could create a controller clas and modify the method prePromptModify